# How to make "require" fail silently in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby program and I need to do require a file, but what I want is to fail silently if the file does not exists. I tried with the following:

```
require '#{var}' rescue nil
```

but without success (seems that the error won't be captured).

The actual code I have now is:

```
require "Livecheckables/#{formula}" if File.exists? File.expand_path("../../Livecheckables/#{formula}.rb", Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)
```

How could I make it in a short and readable way?

Comment: Why don't you enumerate all the livecheckables in a directory and require only the actual existing files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
begin
  require 'blah'
rescue LoadError
end
```

`rescue` is only rescuing StandardError, load error does not fall into this category. Using Exception will rescue form any kind of Exception, including syntax issues within the file or execution problems with a code within required file. Note however it will also rescue from termination signal.

You can always wrap this within a method as well:

```
module Kernel
  def silent_require(name)
    require name
  rescue LoadError
    false
  end
end
```

And then you can use it everywhere:

```
silent_require 'blah'
```

Comment: @Alessio - You can always wrap this within the method on Kernel, updated answer.

Comment: @Alessio: Sure, there is a one-liner: `begin; require 'blah'; rescue Exception; end`

Comment: `rescue LoadError` seem to be more appropriate.

Comment: @Stefan - It will not rescue from parsing error or other errors within the file. Naturally it all depends on what is to be achieved by this. I would use it for making app plugable, in which case I would not like the call to crash because of missed coma or sth in custom plugin.

Comment: *"[...] to fail silently if the file does not exists"* the OP doesn't mention any other error conditions.

Comment: @BroiSatse your answer will also happily silence interrupts, kill signals, out of memory errors, etc. You should **almost never** `rescue Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

As Stefan mentioned in comments above solution proposed by @BroiSatse does more than you asked and can make debugging harder.

You better use this version:

```
begin
  require 'blah'
rescue LoadError => e
  raise e until e.path == 'blah'
end
```

It will fail silently only when your specific `require 'blah'` failed keeping all other LoadErrors untouched as well as other exceptions e.g. NoMethodError or NameError.